libtorch can't detect CUDA, while CUDA runtime can
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "CUDA device count: " << torch::cuda::device_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "CUDA is available: " << (torch::cuda::is_available() ? "Yes" : "No") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cuDNN is available: " << (torch::cuda::cudnn_is_available() ? "Yes" : "No") <<        std::endl;
    int deviceCount;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&deviceCount);
    std::cout << "Number of CUDA devices: " << deviceCount << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Output:
CUDA device count: 0
CUDA is available: No
cuDNN is available: No
Number of CUDA devices: 1

runtime seems to work, torch won't show CUDA
I'm using MSVC 2022, windows 11. I installed latest pytorch with CUDA support
libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.4.0+cu124.zip (I also tried release), my nvcc --version shows:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jun_14_16:44:19_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.6, V12.6.20
Build cuda_12.6.r12.6/compiler.34431801_0

I tried different versions of pytorch with no success. I can access CUDA from python code using pytorch with no problems, but i need to access it in C++

If Windows, you can also detect cuda by DXGI enum and checking Vendor ID 4318

i just need to use libtorch with cuda, but it won't untill it detects cuda device. so detecting cuda outside of torch isn't an issue

Is there a direct ml version to download?

i downloaded libtorch-win-shared-with-deps-2.4.0+cu124.zip and release version of libtorch with cuda support from the official pytorch site, but it won't find any cuda device.

manually loading torch_cuda.dll does fix the problem:
    HMODULE torchCudaDll = LoadLibraryA("torch_cuda.dll");
    if (torchCudaDll == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load torch_cuda.dll. Error code: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

}
    else {
        std::cout << "Successfully loaded torch_cuda.dll" << std::endl;
        //  free the library when you're done:
        // FreeLibrary(torchCudaDll);
    }

apparently that was an old bug

Man, you are a genius...

If you're on Windows (which I assume, because I've never faced this error on Linux), try:
// All you #includes
#include <Windows.h>

// All you code which comes before int main()
int main()
{
  HMODULE loadLib = LoadLibraryA("torch_cuda.dll"); // Ensure torch_cuda.dll is located in you project folder.
  if (loadLib == NULL) std::cout << "Failed to load torch_cuda.dll.\n";

  // All your other code
  FreeLibrary(loadLib); // This may throw errors, make sure to handle correctly
  return 0;
}


Answer is the same as the older answer
